# Calculate total number of Hours asp.net c#

Tags: c#, timespan

I have done the following piece of code to add the Hours and thus calculate total number of hours.

```
   string hour1="48.40";
   string hour2 = "45.35";

    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(hour1.Split('.')[0]),int.Parse(hour1.Split('.')[1]),
                       0);
    TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(hour2.Split('.')[0]),int.Parse(hour2.Split('.')[1]),
               0);

    Double total = (ts.TotalHours) + (ts1.TotalHours);
```

The problem here is when i add `hour1` and `hour2` the `total` comes as **64.25** which actually should have been **64.15**

This is just one of the test case, if i put `hour1`= *40.00* and `hour2`= 40.10 than the value in the total comes as *80.166666666666657* which actually should have been *80.10*

can anyone help me understand what am i doing wrong and what is the correct way to add HOUR and get total number of hours ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets a little strange when you have timestamps put into strings. But if you need to do it like this, this code should work

```
string hour1="48.40";
string hour2 = "45.35";

//find total number of minutes for each hour above  
int minutes1 = int.Parse(hour1.Split('.')[0])*60+int.Parse(hour1.Split('.')[1]);
int minutes2 = int.Parse(hour2.Split('.')[0])*60+int.Parse(hour2.Split('.')[1]);

//calculate back to hours and minutes and reassemble as a string
string result = (minutes1+minutes2)/60+"."+(minutes1+minutes2)%60;
```

And I hope you are expecting **94.15** and not **64.15** in your example above.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you're getting correct result - just mixing minutes and fractional parts of hours.

80 hrs 10 mins is 80 1/6 hours

64 hours 15 mins is 64 1/4 hours

Answer (score 0):

You may use next code to get result you would like to:

```
string hour1 = "48.40";
string hour2 = "45.35";

TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(hour1.Split('.')[0]), int.Parse(hour1.Split('.')[1]),
                               0);
TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(hour2.Split('.')[0]), int.Parse(hour2.Split('.')[1]),
                       0);

TimeSpan total = ts + ts1;

int hours = (int)total.TotalHours;

int minutes = total.Minutes;
```